# Suitable graph to compare predicted and actual values across multiple sites

Tags: r, data-visualization, prediction, accuracy

I would like to make a graph to compare predictions with actual values. 
The graph must be independent of scale and show equal emphasis for over and under prediction.  The purpose is to summarise predictions at a range of sites where the size of predictions and actual values differ.

This is what I've come up with.  Errors are plotted as a correction factor which is 
required to make the prediction equal to the actual values. You can see that having to multiple predictions by 2 to get the actual value plots as the same magnitude as having to multiply predictions by 1/2.  This was inspired by this [plot](http://shinyapps.org/apps/RGraphCompendium/index.php#the-electoral-advantage-of-being-tall-revisited).  Are there other graphs with a similar purpose?

(edited to incorporate suggestion by @rvl)

[image: error plot]

@rvl suggests a plot of log(actual/predicted) as below.

[image: log(actual/predicted)]

(code includes log(actual/prediction) as suggested by @rvl)

```
#Example plot (now includes log version)
library(MASS)

prediction <- c(2, 5, 10, 20, 30)
actual <- rep(10, times = length(prediction))

# Factor needed to multiply the prediction by to equal
# the actual value
(ratio.diff <- actual/prediction)
# [1] 5.0000000 2.0000000 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333

# Make the values to plot
DiffFactor <- function(y,yhat){
  out <- (y/yhat)
  out[out < 1] <- -1/out[out < 1] + 2
  out

}

(diff.factor <- DiffFactor(actual, prediction))
# [1]  5  2  1  0 -1

par(oma = c(1,2,0,0))
plot(diff.factor,
     ylab = '',
     yaxt = 'n',
     las = 1, 
     ylim = c(-3, 5))
abline(h=1, lty=2)

my.at = c( -3 : 5)
my.labels <- c(as.character(fractions(-1/(my.at[ my.at < 1 ] -2))), my.at[my.at >= 1])

axis(side = 2, at = my.at, labels = my.labels, las = 1)
mtext(side = 2, line = 3, text = 'Correction factor required to make prediction =     actual')

#--------------------------------------------------------

# Log version


par(oma = c(1,2,0,0))
plot(log(actual/prediction, base = 2),
     ylab = '',
     yaxt = 'n',
     ylim = c(-3,3),
     las = 1)

abline(h=0, lty=2)

my.at <-  c( -3 : 3)
my.labels <- as.character(fractions(1/(2^rev(my.at))))

axis(side = 2, at = my.at, labels = my.labels, las = 1)
mtext(side = 2, line = 3, text = 'Correction factor required to make prediction = actual')
```

Comment: Typically, people do this using log(actual) - log(predicted) = log(actual/predicted).

Comment: I would like to avoid logs if possible for a couple of reasons - 1. the log scaling will reduce the apparent size of the largest errors, 2.  my intended audience might struggle with a log scale.

Comment: I think if you're going to use your plot, the bottom part of the labels should be 1/2, 1/3, ... -- not -1/2, -1/3, ... . The minus signs are incorrect because the labels refer to proportions, which are all positive. But I still think an ordinary plot with a log scale is the time-honored way of doing it. This is very easy to do in R.